# I have a Problem in Java relating to "ActionEvent" and "actionPerformed"

Tags: java

I am doing 2 programs (cannot have major changes to the layout of the code), but I have an error relating to this line below:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
```

The same problem is for the other program too. Is there a way to fix it (without changing much of the rest, since all of the rest has to be somewhat the same)?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class LionTigersBears extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    //declare variables and color
    double dollars, answer;
    int servicesCode;

    Color darkRed = new Color(160, 50, 0);

    //Create components for applet
    Label promptLabel = new Label("Welcome to Lions, Tigers, and Bears Pet Clinic");
        TextField currencyField = new TextField(20);

    Label outputLabel = new Label ("Choose your services and then press Calculate.");
    Button calculateButton = new Button ("Calculate");

        Checkbox annualvisitBox = new Checkbox("Annual Visit",false);
        Checkbox vaccinationsBox = new Checkbox("Vaccinations",false);
        Checkbox hospitalizationsBox = new Checkbox("Hospitalizations",false);
        Checkbox heartwormBox = new Checkbox("Heartworm",true);
        Checkbox boardingBox = new Checkbox("Boarding",false);
        Checkbox dentistryBox = new Checkbox("Dentistry",false);
        Checkbox labworkBox = new Checkbox("Lab Work",false);
        Checkbox prescriptionsBox = new Checkbox("Prescriptions",false);
        Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox("",true);


    public void init ()
    {
        setBackground(darkRed);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        add(promptLabel);

        add(annualvisitBox);
        annualvisitBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(vaccinationsBox);
        vaccinationsBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(hospitalizationsBox);
        hospitalizationsBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(heartwormBox);
        heartwormBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(boardingBox);
        boardingBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(dentistryBox);
        dentistryBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(labworkBox);
        labworkBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(prescriptionsBox);
        prescriptionsBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(calculateButton);
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(outputLabel);

        try
        {
            totalCost = gettotalCost();
            serviceCode = getCode();
            answer = gettotalCost();
            output(answer,dollars);
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
        }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        double totalCost = 0;

        if (annualvisitBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (vaccinationsBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (hospitalizationsBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (annualvisitBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (heartwormBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (boardingBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (dentistryBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost+ 20;
        if (labworkBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
        if (prescriptionsBox.getState()) totalCost = totalCost + 20;
    }
    return code;

    outputLabel.setText("The total cost is "+ totalCost);
    annualvisitBox.setState(false);
    vaccinationsBox.setState(false);
    hospitalizationsBox.setState(false);
    heartwormBox.setState(false);
    boardingBox.setState(false);
    dentistryBox.setState(false);
    labwork.setState(false);
    prescriptions.setState(false);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please tell us which problem you have with the line you mention, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: LionsTigersBears.java:70: illegal start of expression
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
 ^
LionsTigersBears.java:70: illegal start of expression
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        ^
LionsTigersBears.java:70: ';' expected
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                            ^
LionsTigersBears.java:70: ';' expected
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                                           ^

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to define a method within another method.  That's a syntax error in Java.  Move your `actionPerformed` method outside your `init` method.

Comment: If I do that, then I get 26 more errors (that are not really errors at all).

Comment: @user473973: It looks like you're accessing the `totalCost` variable outside the scope where it's defined in `actionPerformed`.  I think you mean for that to be a class variable, not local to `actionPerformed`.